# Jquery animate backgroundColor not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a background color fade in (and then eventually I'll want it to fade back out) when you click a button.  I can get the background to change color with this:

```
$("#" + lblqty).css("background","#e9f1ff");
```

But when I try to use animate (like below), it doesn't work. Nothing happens and I don't even get a javascript error:

```
$("#" + lblqty).animate({ backgroundColor: "#e9f1ff"}, 800);
```

I put the code in JSFiddle so you can see it in action.  What should happen is when you click on "item" or check the checkbox, a div should appear that shows "Quantity 1" and a + and - sign.  When you click the + sign, it should increase the quantity by 1 and the background should change color.  Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/ew52wyLm/1/

```js
$(".calccheckbox").change(function() {
  var checkid = $(this).attr("id");
  var qtyid = "qty_" + checkid;
  var lblqty = "qtylbl_" + checkid;
  var aic = "aic_" + checkid;
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).attr("value", checkid + "_1");
    $("#" + qtyid).html("1");
    $("#" + lblqty).show(300);
    // $("#" + aic).css("background","#b6d1ff");
    // $("#" + lblqty).css("background","#e9f1ff");        
  } else {
    $(this).attr("value", checkid);
    $("#" + qtyid).html("");
    $("#" + lblqty).hide(300);
  }
});
$(".calcaddbutton, .calcremovebutton").click(function(event) {
  var button = $(this);
  var checkid = $(this).attr("id");
  checkid = checkid.slice(3);
  var qtyid = "qty_" + checkid;
  var qty = $("#" + qtyid).html();
  var aic = "aic_" + checkid;
  var lblqty = "qtylbl_" + checkid;
  if (button.hasClass("calcaddbutton")) {
    if (qty > 49) {
      alert("You may only add 50 of each item");
    } else {
      qty++;
      $("#" + qtyid).html(qty);
      $("#" + checkid).attr("value", checkid + "_" + qty);
      // $("#" + lblqty).css("background","#e9f1ff");
      $("#" + lblqty).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#e9f1ff"
      }, 800);
    }
  }
  if (button.hasClass("calcremovebutton")) {
    if (qty < 2) {
      $("#" + qtyid).html("");
      $("#" + checkid).attr("value", checkid);
      var lblqty = "qtylbl_" + checkid;
      $("#" + lblqty).hide(300);
      $("#" + checkid).attr("checked", false);
    } else {
      qty--;
      $("#" + qtyid).html(qty);
      $("#" + checkid).attr("value", checkid + "_" + qty);
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="additemcontainer">
  <div id="aic_1170">
    <label for="1170">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calccheckbox" value="1170" name="items[]" id="1170" />Item</label>
  </div>
  <div class="qtylbl" style="display:none;" id="qtylbl_1170">Quantity: <span class="qty" id="qty_1170"></span> 
    <a href="#" class="calcaddbutton" id="add1170">
      <div class="calcbuttoncontainer"><span class="calcbutton glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
      </div>
    </a> <a href="#" class="calcremovebutton" id="rem1170"><span class="calcbutton glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't animate colors, you'll need a plugin or jQuery UI for that ?

Comment: Just read the API *most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be*

Answer (score 1):

You cannot animate the background-color with jQuery's default animate function.

What you can do, however, is position another div with a different color underneath your original div, and then animate the opacity on the original div, so that the color of the underlying div shows through, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate background color using Jquery UI library.

Include your jquery library and the jquery ui library, and it should work.

http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

As multiple people mentioned, this isn't possible to do with jQuery, but it is possible with Velocity.js.  And Velocity.js animations perform much better, especially on mobile!